# why the word count job failed on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I run a word count job on Hadoop.I have checked the HDFS and yarn were all in running before the job.but when the job started,`hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar wordcount /input /output`.
The job failed，seems like the master can't be connected.

```
2021-12-17 03:33:37,196 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032
2021-12-17 03:33:38,366 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:39,371 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:40,379 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:41,381 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:42,384 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:43,388 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:44,392 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:45,395 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:46,403 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:47,406 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:48,429 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:49,430 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:50,433 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:51,439 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:52,442 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:53,444 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:54,453 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:55,458 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:56,462 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:57,465 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.18.0.2:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-12-17 03:33:57,470 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.net.ConnectException: Call From hadoop-master/172.18.0.2 to hadoop-master:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication over null after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 34878ms.
```

Then I typed jps,found that the resourceManager has quit.

```
enter code ^Croot@hadoop-master:~# jps
8224 NodeManager
631 SecondaryNameNode
423 DataNode
8634 Jps
255 NameNode
```

Comment: Are you on linux/windows?

Comment: `Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`